# How to animate a page like using a "camera" on a 2d plane, specifically panning and zooming?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, animation, angular-animations

I've got a assignment where I need to create a 3x3 grid of rectangles, where a person can click one of those rectangles and the page zooms in on that rectangle, so it's now screen-filling.
I've got that working in Angular 6 by just using their animation system and doing `transform: scale(3)` and a `translateX`/`translateY`, depending on which one of the rectangles has been clicked. So, no problem there. (see the gif below)

[image: GIF of what already works]

However, I also need to create 2 or 3 rectangles, that are shown before the grid is shown. So, when the user visits the page, he first sees 1 rectangle, filling the screen, clicks on "next", and then sees the grid.

Basically, I want to have a "top-down" view of my DOM, being able to zoom one of the rectangles or zoom out and see the grid.

I was thinking about ditching the DOM and using three.js or pixi.js, but since I'm on a *really* tight deadline, I thought about coming here and asking you guru's what you think is best.

So, what's the best way to create a whole bunch of rectangles and be able to zoom in, out, and move around between them? Thanks a lot in advance!

Please, if you need more info, leave a comment :)

Comment: Take a look at [impress.js](https://github.com/impress/impress.js/)

Comment: @Vanojx1 definitely taking a look at that! Thanks